# Flutter app triggering anti-virus on windows

Tags: windows, flutter

The windows exe file of my Flutter developed application triggers an anti-virus checkup by Avast when it's started. The file comes up clean, but it's not a very user-friendly experience, since I'm planning a public release.

I'm not a windows developer so I'm kinda in the dark here... what could be the cause and is there anything I can do to prevent it? Avast staff is not very helpful on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Observed with flutter_windows_1.17.2-stable.zip

After extracting Flutter SDK and typing 'flutter doctor' on command prompt, dart.exe from path 'flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin' gets deleted and anti-virus software pops-up a message stating the file is recognized as malware and either gets deleted or quarantined.

Workaround:
Download latest Dart SDK from https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive. (I used 2.8.3 x64)
Extract it and replace the dart-sdk folder in flutter SDK location 'flutter\bin\cache'

Now running 'flutter doctor' executes properly and validates system. With files from Dart SDK repository there are no anti-virus warnings

source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58302